# Parsing timestamp using sed and embedded command

Tags: shell, sed, date-parsing

There's a file with some lines containing some text and either date or time stamp:

```
...
string1-20141001
string2-1414368000000
string3-1414454400000
...
```

I want to quickly convert time stamps to dates, like this:

```
$ date -d @1414368000 +"%Y%m%d"
20141027
```

and I want to do this dynamically with `sed` or some similar command line tool. For testing I unsuccessfully use this:

```
$ echo "something-1414454400000" | sed "s/-\(..........\)...$/-$(date -d @\\1 +'%Y%m%d')/"
date: invalid date '@\\1'
something-
```

but `echo`ing seems to be working:

```
$ echo "something-1414454400000" | sed "s/-\(..........\)...$/-$(echo \\1)/"
something-1414454400
```

so what could be done?

Comment: "but echoing seems to be working" - nope.

Comment: you have a fundamental misunderstand, the shell evaluates the arguments first before calling the application. just `echo` what you wanted to pass and you'll see.

Comment: `bash -x` will help you understand it.

Comment: Better you clarify about your input file. Do you want to replace each line starting with same prefix e.g. `something-` with date's output?

Comment: Ok, I see it. Any suggestions what other tools could I use to achieve desirable effect?

Comment: in (my biased) preference order: python, ruby, perl, php. it's also doable in bash, but I would put that to the end of my list, simply because it's going to be the slowest and least maintainable. the code won't look nice either. hard to find anything in favor of it.

Comment: @anubhava, no, I want to replace line's ending, if it has specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting what's happening here. Some pointers:

- Always single-quote your regex for sed, if possible, when using BASH (etc), *especially* if using special characters like`$`. This is why `date` is being run (with `-d @\\1`) **before sed even gets involved**.
- Your "working" echo example isn't, actually (I believe): `echo \\1` produces `\1` (and as above, will do so before sed even gets invoked). This then happens to valid sed replacement syntax, so will substitute your group on the LHS, which is why the output looks *about right*.
- Note that by using `-r`, you can use easier / more advanced regex syntax.

Hard to say exactly what to do without a bit more context, but to fix the immediate problems, try something like:

```
echo "something-1414454400000" | sed -re 's/-([0-9]{10,}).+/-$(date -d @\1 +"%Y%m%d")/'
```

which produces: `$(date -d @1414454400)` (which you can then pipe to `sh`)

Or for a more complete solution, you can change the regex to produce a shell command directly, and pipe it:

```
echo "something-1414454400000" | sed -re 's/(.*-)([0-9]{10,10}).+/echo \1$(date -d @\2 \"+%Y%M%d\")/' | sh
```

..producing `something-20140028`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `BASH`:

```
while read -r p; do
   if [[ "$p" =~ ^(.+-)([0-9]{10}).{3}$ ]]; then
      echo -n "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      date -d "@${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" +"%Y%m%d"
   else
      echo "$p"
   fi
done < file
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string1-20141001
string2-20141026
string3-20141027
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F- 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    $2 ~ /^[0-9]{13}$/ {
        "date -d@" $2/1000 " +%Y%m%d " | getline t; $2=t }1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this command. I have checked it. It is working on your inputs.

```
cat file | sed -E "s,(.*)-(.*),\1-`date -d @1414368000 +'%Y%m%d'`,g"
```